# Uncaught NSException when keyboard present

Tags: swift, xcode, exception

I have a basic login page which takes two values (username and password), and these details are passed to my server, where I use PHP to parse the result and return a JSON array.

Everything works fine; I can login correctly, the correct error alerts appear on bad logins, etc.. however whenever I try to login into the application WHILE the keyboard is not minimized:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I was hoping someone might have a bit of an idea why this is? My entire error thread is as follows:

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
0x18bb6700c <+0>:  movz   x16, #0x148
0x18bb67010 <+4>:  svc    #0x80
->0x18bb67014 <+8>:  b.lo   0x18bb6702c               ; <+32>
0x18bb67018 <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-16]!
0x18bb6701c <+16>: mov    x29, sp
0x18bb67020 <+20>: bl     0x18bb4a7d0               ; cerror_nocancel
0x18bb67024 <+24>: mov    sp, x29
0x18bb67028 <+28>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #16
0x18bb6702c <+32>: ret
```

[I have attached a screenshot of my app for you to get a clearer pic of what I mean that the keyboard is not minimized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ02R.jpg)

[Complete debugger output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1X2X.jpg)

Comment: Set an exception breakpoint in Xcode to get more information. There are two pieces of info that are crucial: a) what kind of exception is being triggered, and b) what is the stack trace when it happens

Comment: Okay, I have done so. It shows the line throwing the error which is an alert being presented to the screen. Attached image

Comment: What exception is being thrown? Can you see anything about the exception in the Output area in Xcode? Also, can you share the actual stack trace? You can type `bt` in the debugger when you're paused to get a textual representation.

Comment: Okay apologies if I'm a little slow, I'm new to swift.. that being said for the first bit I believe the output shows `Error:    Unable to capture view hierarchy.
Details:  Error fetching view hierarchy: (
    "Exception gathering view hierarchy information: -[UIApplication _performWithUICACommitStateSnapshotting:] must be called on the main thread 
(`

Comment: No problem! That exception message clears everything up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is telling you not to perform UI operations on a background thread. You need to wrap any code that touches the UI in a dispatch to the main thread:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // set up and present alert
}
```

Generally, any time you're using a class that starts with `UI` or has `View` in the name, you need to be on the main thread.

Comment: DUDE! Thank you SO SO much! Perfect, it works! Thank you SO much for your time!